# How to find rows count for each column of an excel sheet in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, rows

I am trying to find the number of rows in each column of an excel sheet but Excel.Range Rows.Count always returns the max number of rows used in excel.
I have tried running the code for each column, still it returns the max number  of rows used. Please help me out!

```
   Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
   Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\excelData2.xlsx");
   Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
   Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        List<int> rowCountList = new List<int> () ;

        for (int ja=1; ja<=colCount; ja++)
        {
            Excel.Range xlRange1 = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            rowCountList.Add(xlRange1.Rows.Count);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this does what you want, add it within the for loop ...

```
var lastRow = xlWorksheet.Cells[xlWorksheet.Rows.Count,ja].End[XlDirection.xlUp].Row;
```